# Parameterized test in GoogleTest does not work as expected

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm just started learning googletesting and I'm playing around with it. 
I want to use parameterized test to check if the value returned by a function member of a class is what it should be.
I have declared a class named 'myClass' in which I set a value of a variable with constructor and I also have a public function 'retA()' that returns it's value.

Then I have declared a fixture class in which I create an object(obj) of 'myClass', instatiate member a with constructor and assign the value of obj.retA() function to an int value 'result'. Then I wrote a 'TEST_P' in which I'm checking if result is what I expect it to be and instatiate the TEST_P. Then in the main I'm starting all tests.

My test fails when I only pass the argument which should not make the test fail and I do not understand why :( (result should be 3 I think)

Please help me clear this up. Thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gtest\gtest.h"
#include "gmock\gmock.h"
#include "Tests.cpp"

class myClass
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    myClass() {}
    myClass(int a) { a = this->a; }
    void setA(int val) { a = val; }
    int retA() { return a; }
};

class myFixture : public ::testing::TestWithParam<int>
{
public:
    int result;

    myFixture()
    {
        myClass obj( GetParam() );
        result = obj.retA();
    }
};

TEST_P(myFixture, Test1) {
    // Inside a test, access the test parameter with the GetParam() method
    // of the TestWithParam<T> class:
    ASSERT_EQ(3, result);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
    InstantiationName, myFixture, ::testing::Values(3);
);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did everything perfectly correct. Expect on little thing, very hard to find... ;)

In your Class under Test (`myClass`), in the constructor `this` is reversed. It should look like this:

```
myClass(int a) { this->a = a; }
```